# How to use Google Calendar's watch method inside a Chrome Extension without a server

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension is it possible to use Google Calendar's API [watch method](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) to receive push notifications instead of pollling without hosting my own server?

Can Firebase/FCM or [chrome.gcm](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm) provide a solution? cloud based perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the long polling but you'd still have to host a server even for the FCM.

I'd suggest you;

- Go with [Heroku](https://heroku.com), set up a free NodeJS dyno for your server. You can use the free MongoDB addon as your DB. Use the [guide here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) to setup the server.
- Setup FCM client in your extension using the [guide here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client). Request the notification permission and get token on [install](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) or if you have a login system in your extension, after user has authorized. Send the token to your server and save in DB against that user's id or any other unique id that you can track from Calendar notification.
- Use the Heroku app URL as target in Watch API. So all the notifications will be delivered to your Heroku instance.

When a notification is received from Calendar API;

- Use any form of id in that notification and find the user's device/FCM token from DB.
- Use that token as `to` and [send message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) to that device. Handle the message on device as you want.

  Calendar API -> Heroku Server -> FCM Server -> User Device

Means no need for 'long polling'. Your notifications will be delivered in realtime. Depending on the usage, you could also keep the Heroku instance free.

Comment: Very insightful and love all the links. Do you have experience with a push notification server? My fear is that the load could be quite heavy as I have several extensions with millions of users.

Comment: I do @Jason. I think you'd be okay using Heroku or any other cloud service (AWS, Google Cloud, etc.). Because they scale very well. Or you can increase the resource on an instance/dyno to meet your needs.

If you are going to use NodeJS then use [clusters](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-node-js-cluster-for-speeding-up-your-apps/). NodeJS is great for handling concurrent load.